# Formatting issue adding folder names to listbox C#

Tags: c#, listbox

I am trying to populate a listbox with folder names. The code that I am using does work, but the format is not what I am looking for.

```
string MyPath= Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\MyProgram\\Test\\");


        string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(MyPath);
    foreach(string fols in folders)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(fols);
    }
```

"C:\Users....\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MyProgram\Test\Data" is what shows up in the listbox. I would like it to only show all the folders within the Test directory and excluding everything else. How can I make this possible? Thank you.

Comment: `Path.GetFileName(s)` will trim it to the last folder (even though it says  GetFILEname).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to remove all characters upto and including the folder name.

```
var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\MyProgram\\Test\\");
foreach (var folder in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(folder.Remove(0, path.Length));
}
```